# Linked list problem (Leetcode) - understanding inputs

Tags: python, list, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I am starting to complete some Leetcode problems, having finished an online Data Structures and Algorithms course, but I'm struggling to understand what some of the input variables represent. I've included one of the solutions as an example. The problem gives me the head of a sorted linked list as input and asks me to remove all duplicates and return a new linked list as a solution.

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
class Solution:
    def deleteDuplicates(self, head: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        if head is None:
            return head
        pt=head
        prev=pt
        pt=pt.next
        while pt:
            if pt.val==prev.val:
# If the two nodes have the same value, then prev.next skips the current position of pt and moves two forward
                prev.next=pt.next
                pt=pt.next
            else:
                prev=pt
                pt=pt.next
        return head
```

What I don't understand is the meaning of the word 'head' here. For instance, if I have as an (incorrect) solution only one line of code that just returns head, the output will simply be equal to all of the inputs, implying that head is just the pointer that automatically iterates through all of the input values unless instructed to do otherwise. Yet I haven't set up any iteration, while-loop etc, so why would the head variable move through the members of the input list automatically? Ordinarily, of course, the head is simply a pointer to the first member of the linked list. Then we set up code that allows us to iterate through the list while perhaps bringing a second pointer into play etc.

Frankly, for that matter (and here I'm going to reveal the extent of my confusion), I don't really understand how the history of the pointers' iteration through the linked list gives rise to a set of unique, non-duplicate values that can be returned as head in the solution presented. Prev is the only pointer that skips duplicate values, as I understand ('if pt.val == prev.val// prev.next = pt.next...'), so how is it that by returning head here, we return the history of prev...? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is your linked list sorted ? also can you use extra space

Comment: Yes, linked list is sorted at the start. I apologise but I don't understand what you mean by 'can you use extra space'? If I wanted, the Leetcode would accept a brute force solution but this is probably now what you're referring to..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
class Solution:
    def deleteDuplicates(self, head: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        temp = head
        seen = set() # this will keep track if element is duplicate or not
        prev = head  # this will keep track of previous node
        while temp:
            if temp.val not in seen:
                seen.add(temp.val)
                prev = temp # update prev here only because if we update it in else as well then it can lead to point next of lost node you can get this by drawing this on paper
            else:
                prev.next = temp.next
            
            temp = temp.next
            
        return head
```

Comment: If I return seen, it gives the correct values but in the form of a set whereas 'the expected return type is ListNode'

Comment: I have edited, now check

Comment: Now head just returns as output the same inputs unchanged.

Comment: Can you give me the link to the problem so that I can try because it is becoming difficult to guess the correct output

Comment: Yes, of course: https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-list/

Comment: @Dommy1 now check it will run

Comment: It does work - thank you and I've upvoted -, though I'm still struggling to understand how the return head variable interacts with the two pointers in our algorithm to produce the correct result since, in your algorithm, prev is the only pointer that skips duplicate values, I believe?

Comment: @Dommy1 I have added some comments now check

Comment: Ok, that's great: I understand now. Thank you very much for taking the time to respond so carefully. I will mark as solved.